# DataGridView column filter using datatable as source

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

In c# I am trying to have column dropdown filtering while using a datatable as the datasource with an unknown number of columns and rows. All example and help I have found refers to a database with known column data but I am dealing with multiple databases and need to have a dynamic column filter. Just like excel or powerpivot would do. So if a database is changed and columns are removed or added it will still work.

Comment: I started writting the answer, then realized that my solution is really complicated to describe, so I'll give you just a little hint instead: you may want to consider using DataView instead of DataTable as a DataGridView's DataSource. It can be sorted, and it has string RowFilter property, so column names and filtered values can be passed dynamically as strings (e.g. RowFilter=myColName+"="+myFilteredValue; or RowFilter=myColName+" IN ("+myFilteredValueList +")";) You can use SQL-like syntax with it. Not as elegant as LINQ but you don't have to predefine columns.

Comment: Thats one option but I would prefer to use the datatable as source, saves a lot of trouble importing data.

Comment: there is DataTable.DefaultView. With DataView you just apply filtering logic on top of your DataTable. I don't even think you have to change DataGridView's source when filtering. Although creating custom context menus for column headers and implementing filtering logic can be a lot of work, so maybe using some existing solution may be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here
[AdvancedDataGridView https://adgv.codeplex.com/](https://adgv.codeplex.com/)